# Есть ли запрос к ISS MOEX, который запрашивает данные для построения графиков («свечей»)?

Tags: json, xml

Люди, которые работали с ISS MOEX, подскажите, как вы строили графики котировок конкретной акции? Есть ли вообще в свободном доступе данные об этом прошлых лет? В руководстве разработчика написано: "В рамках интерфейса доступны следующие типы информации: статические данные о
рынках (режимы торгов и их группы, финансовые инструменты и их описание), данные
для построения графиков («свечей»), сделки (анонимно), котировки, итоги торгов,
различные метаданные."

Только вот какие это данные, что они из себя представляют - не понял. :/

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заходим на https://iss.moex.com/iss/reference/ там видим все возможные запросы. Находим [свечи](https://iss.moex.com/iss/reference/155), читаем описание в котором сказано, что url строится по шаблону `/iss/engines/[engine]/markets/[market]/securities/[security]/candles` и описаны дополнительные параметры. Строим ссылку, например (с выводом в json):

http://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/shares/securities/SBER/candles.json?from=2021-01-01&till=2021-01-30&interval=10

Данные для свечей по Сбербанку с 1 по 30 января 2021 получены.